# How to understand if a property of a property of my class has changed

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have the following class

```
public class A {
   private int number;

   public int getNumber(){
       return number;
   }
   public void setNumber(int number){
       this.number = number;
   }
}
```

and then class B which has as a property an object of class A.

```
public class B {
    private A member;

    public A getMember() {
         return member;
    }
    public void setMember(A member) {
          this.member = member;
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is to have class B notified when the integer number in class A is changed.

I would like to have the notification mechanism without the use of Observable and Observer. Any ideas ? Is there any suitable pattern except the observer pattern ?

EDIT: The reason that I do not want to use the observer again is because class B already extends java.util.Observable and my ultimate goal is to let the observer of class B to know about the changes in

> private member A;

Comment: listener? Or you consider it similar to observable?

Comment: Yes, quantum mechanics is a possibility! Seriously, what about simply observing?

Comment: A listener / event pattern could work fine here?

Comment: what do you want to achieve? You could use a reference from A to B or something like an event bus (for example [Google Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/EventBusExplained)), but in my point of view an observer fits the most in your example

Comment: Why does this odd question have three up-votes?!

Comment: @Smutje it's also possible without observer. See my suggestion

Comment: @Duncan I think the question is good and also in it has solution

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy As you use an inner class, you hide the observing and replace it through the access from containee to containing class, I don't see the conceptual difference to an observer.

Comment: @Smutje What about proxy pattern?

Comment: I would say that the in comparison to the other solution using a PropertyChangeListener would work fine ...

Answer (score 0):

Declare your class A as interface and return in B an internal delegate implementation of this interface (Proxy pattern).

Something like this

```
public interface A {
  void setNumber(int n);
  int getNumber();
}

public class B {
  private A member;
  private class AImpl implements A {
    public void setNumber(int n) {
      member.setNumber(n);
      notifyB();
    }
    public int getNumber() {
      int res = member.getNumber();
      notifyB();
      return res;
    }
  }
  public A getMember() {
    return new AImpl();
  }
  public void setMember(A member) {
    this.member = member;
  }
  private void notifyB() {
    // notification
  }
}
```

Alternative you can also use the class `Proxy` but interface is the preferrable way to do this.

Answer (score -1):

If is is plausible, you can try making class A immutable. Then when you change A what you really do is construct a new immutable object (like String). Then to chance A you must then use B's set method to replace A with the new A whenever you change anything.

This pattern is a little harder to use for the client, but it does mean that class B is automatically notified, since you can only change a part of the A in B by calling the set method.

You basically just have to imagine that A is a string, when you are using this pattern, so you create a new string, and then call set because string is immutable.